# How to Replace Page Numbers by Item Numbers in the Index

Tags: pdftex, enumerate, indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\hoffset 10pt \voffset -45pt
\oddsidemargin 12pt \evensidemargin 10pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8.35in \textwidth 6.25in
\headsep 25pt \marginparwidth 35pt


\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}


% % The colored box that encloses the item number.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=red!75!black,
    top=.75pt,
    left=1pt,
    right=1pt,
    bottom=.5pt,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}


\parindent 0pt

% % FANCY ENUMERATE positioning the enumerated colored box above the text.
\newcounter{cenum}
\newcommand\cenumsep{}  
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
    \setcounter{cenum}{0}%
    \setlength\parskip\bigskipamount
    %  \begin{center}%
}{%
    %  \end{center}%
}

\newcommand\citemx[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\refstepcounter{cenum}%
\par\cenumsep\logo{\textcolor{white}{\arabic{cenum}}}%
%\par\cenumsep\logo{\arabic{cenum}}%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \hspace*{12pt}#1  % left/right space
    \vspace*{0.5ex}% vertical adjustment
\end{minipage}
\par\nobreak\vskip-\parskip\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces% \medskip is the distance between label and text, change as needed
}


% NEW SYMBOL DEFINITIONS

\newcommand{\R}{\textcolor{red}{{\scalefont{1.25}{$\bullet\hspace*{.15em}$}}}}
\newcommand{\B}{\textcolor{blue}{{\scalefont{1.25}{$\bullet\hspace*{.15em}$}}}}



%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
    %\large
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
%\setlength\itemsep{1em plus 1fil}
%\interlinepenalty=10000
        \begin{cenumerate}
            \citemx{\R\R\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \B\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\R} \lipsum[4] \index{Entry item i}
            
            \citemx{\B\B\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\B\R\R} \lipsum[1] \index{Entry item ii}
            
            \citemx{\B\B\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\B\R\R} \lipsum[2] \index{Entry item iii}
            
            \citemx{\B\B\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\B\R\R} \lipsum[5] \index{Entry item iv}
            
            \citemx{\B\B\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\B\R\R} \lipsum[5] \index{Entry item v}
            
            \citemx{\B\B\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\B\R\R} \lipsum[1] \index{Entry item vi}
            
            \citemx{\B\B\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\B\R\R} \lipsum[5] \index{Entry item vii}
            
            \citemx{\B\B\B\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\R\R\B \hspace*{.08em} \R\B\R\R} \lipsum[5] \index{Entry item viii}
        \end{cenumerate}
    \end{multicols}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex

\vspace{1cm}\centering\large Instead of page numbers, I would like item (i.e., citemx) numbers.    
\end{document}
```

which produces (only some pictured) the customized itemization

[image]

In the actual document, I anticipate there will be hundreds of such items containing actual, as well as coded descriptions of each item---with several items on each page. Thus, an index that displays the item number rather than the page number is desired.

The index produced by the MWE is

[image]

QUESTION: How may the code given in the MWE be modified in order for the Index to display items (`\citemx` numbers) instead of page numbers for each index item?

Thank you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187038/how-to-mention-section-number-in-index-created-by-imakeidx seems related (uses `xindy` as index processor)

Comment: also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180141/how-to-make-index-entries-refer-to-section-numbers-and-or-figure-table-numbers

Comment: This one too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137223/custom-numbers-for-index (`glossaries` with `counter=xxx`)

Comment: with regular `makeindex`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298519/using-imakeidx-with-custom-page-numbering and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352759/index-by-section-subsection/352765

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for these posts; I recall (I think) having looked at some of them before posting the question. One difference between my  question and some of your links, for example, is the redefining of the enumerate environment  to accommodate both the fancy item display, as well as the adjoining binary code. I have tried various adaptations, but so far, nothing has worked. I am hoping that an expert might post a working answer.